# Android Emulator: Can not connect to internet for some apps behind proxy

Tags: android, android-emulator, proxy, android-testing

Purpose: To access the application in emulator through proxy

What I did: Successfully launched emulator and set Burp proxy in emulator network setting. I can access net in browser and some of application (flipkart, imdb) through proxy. 
In Burp I set "CA Signed per host certificate" for SSL setting 
I'm using: ADB 1.0.31, Android Emulator Version 22.0.4.0

Problem: But some of application which asks authentication first (like evernote, lookout etc) an error occurs saying "There's a problem in internet connection"

Is this problem because of SSL certificate or anything else.

Comment: In Android 4.2.2 there is a known connection problem for application using proxy with authentication.

Comment: I am using Android 4.0